# Three tables join using CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have three tables which I have to join. I'm not a good sql writer. Can please sombody help me to prepare this using joins,

branches

```
branch_id | branch_name | branch_address
1           name1           address1
```

branch_services

```
bs_id | branch_id | service_id
1       1           1
2       1           2
3       1           4
```

services

```
service_id | service_name
1               service1
2               service2
3               service3
4               service4
```

I need to select * from branches table and service_names related to each branch like this

Result

```
1 | name1 | address1 | service1 service2 service4 |
```

---

While i'm searching found something call group_concat.It works. But how to use it with CI???

Comment: pls add your wanted structure

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal please check now

Comment: 1 | name1 | address1 | service1 |                                        1 | name1 | address1 | service2 |                                     1 | name1 | address1 | service4 |    you need this ??

Comment: I need to concat services in one row. Like example is given above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question so that someone find it usefull,

```
$this->db->select("branches.branch_name, branches.branch_address, group_concat(services.service_name)");
$this->db->from("branches");
$this->db->join("branch_services", "branches.id = branch_services.branch_id", "left");
$this->db->join("services", "branch_services.service_id = services.id", "left");
$query = $this->db->get();
```

group_concat is the miracle point

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('branches');
$this->db->join('branch_services','branches.branch_id = branch_services.branch_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('services','branch_services.service_id = services.service_id', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows() != 0)
       return $query->result_array();
else
       return false;
```

use joins like left,right,inner according to your need

Comment: @Dushan do you check my answer??

Comment: all services in one column

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested but try this

```
SELECT branches.*, services.service_name FROM branches LEFT JOIN branch_services ON branches.branch_id = branch_services.branch_id LEFT JOIN services ON services.service_id = branch_services.service_id
```

Comment: this is not working. This will select only one service from the services table. But there can be multiple services providing by one branch. Added sample to my question.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code:**

```
$this->db->select("branches.branch_name, branches.branch_address, services.service_name");
$this->db->from("branches");
$this->db->join("branch_services", "branches.id = branch_services.branch_id", "inner");
$this->db->join("services", "branch_services.service_id = services.id", "inner");
$query = $this->db->get();

$result = array();
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $result = $query->result_array();
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
```

**This will print below result (as expected):**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [branch_name] => name1
            [branch_address] => address1
            [service_name] => service1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [branch_name] => name1
            [branch_address] => address1
            [service_name] => service2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [branch_name] => name1
            [branch_address] => address1
            [service_name] => service4
        )

)
```